# Cannot edit articles on Careers CV

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, article

Changing the title or description of an article and pressing "save" gets stuck in "saving ...". Firebug shows a 500.

This started yesterday, but I was lazy, so I waited a day to see if it would go away by itself.

Comment: [what browser](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need) do you use?

Comment: Pale Moon 9.2. Also tried on IE9.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for the report gidyn.  This is fixed now.